# i have multiple data for a colum item_id in a table and only wants one of each value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a table `T_HISTORY` which can have multiple entries for an `item_ID`

I want one for each `item_id`

```
 SELECT * FROM T_HISTORY WHERE EVENT_CD = 'comment'
```

This returns  following data:

```
HIST_ID  item_id  ITEM_TYPE         EVENT_CD    STATE           USER_NM      EVENT_DT
1953     115      SOURCE_ITEM_ID    COMMENT     AP Exception    proc2        2016-04-20 11:24:56.207
5254     137      SOURCE_ITEM_ID    COMMENT     Final Approval  bnunn        2016-05-05 14:52:50.800
7120     255      SOURCE_ITEM_ID    COMMENT     AP Exception    bnunn        2016-05-18 11:15:47.657
17082    424      SOURCE_ITEM_ID    COMMENT     AP Exception    admincor360  2016-12-08 01:56:30.670
17086    424      SOURCE_ITEM_ID    COMMENT     AP Exception    admincor360  2016-12-08 02:14:01.743
```

Comment: if you have multiple items with same ID, which one should be selected?

Comment: it is also giving the date and i want entry with later date and it will be more helpful if this can be done in a view

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY EVENT_DT DESC)` More that a hint

Comment: and how can i use this row number in where condition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a derived table to order your data and then select just the row you require:

```
with cte
as
(
    select HIST_ID
          ,ITEM_ID
          ,ITEM_TYPE
          ,EVENT_CD
          ,STATE
          ,USER_NM
          ,EVENT_DT
          ,row_number() over (partition by ITEM_ID order by EVENT_DT desc) as rn
    from T_HISTORY
    where EVENT_CD = 'comment'
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Comment: I'd include an order by just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY EVENT_DT DESC) rn, *
      FROM T_HISTORY
      WHERE EVENT_CD = 'comment') sorted
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Solution was provided by Mihai in the comments. This can be used inside a view as well.

Comment: Thanks @Jens this helps alot